# Is it possible to restrict a GitHub personal access token to a particular repository?

Tags: api, web-services, github

I've been using the GitHub API / web services recently. I interact with it using the personal access token (PAT).

When creating a personal access token you can restrict its usage, for security, in several aspects as shown in the image. However, it would be nice to combine this set of permissions with particular repositories. Is there a way to do this?

[image]